# How do i disable doubleclicking on the header of a datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, double-click

I have a datagridview in my application that has some rows in it. I want to user to be able to double click on the row and have it do something. But if they double click on the header, it also does the same action using the highlighted row. Double clicking the header does the same thing as double clicking on a row. I don't want to disable the header and disable column sorting, I just want to disable double clicking on the header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a boolean variable in your form's class called **EnableRowHeaderDoubleClick**
and set it to false
then add this code

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_RowHeaderMouseDoubleClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.RowHeaderMouseDoubleClick
    If EnableRowHeaderDoubleClick = False Then Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

In either `CellDoubleClick` or `CellContentDoubleClick` event you can use the following code:

```
If e.RowIndex <> -1 Then
    'Trigger some actions
End If
```

You might also use `e.ColumnIndex <> -1` to avoid double clicking on the row header.

Comment: using e as MousEventArgs, I get a message saying rowIndex is not a memeber of MouseEventArgs, I get the same message using System.EventArgs.

Comment: What event are you using? you don't declare e as MouseEventArgs.. just use the following event: `Private Sub DataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellDoubleClick` and replace 'DataGridView1' with your DGV name